# sunspot and solr

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, solr, sunspot

I'm currently try to get my sunspot / solr to work. In Dev its all fine and good. But when it comes to production, I'll get the following error.

```
RSolr::RequestError (Solr Response: Not Found):
  app/controllers/examples_controller.rb:48:in `update'
```

sunspot.yml looks like this:

```
 solr:
    hostname: localhost
    port: 8983
    path: '/opt/apache-solr-3.3.0/example'
    log_level: WARNING
    pid_dir: '/var/run'
```

Can anybody sort that out?

Comment: Looks like solr is not available, do a "curl http://localhost:8983/solr" and see what you get.

Comment: Hi Maurício, I'll get the webconsole of solr. It works. So much for the good part...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `path` option is the path component of your Solr server's URL. It should read `/solr` rather than the filesystem path you have now. As it is, Sunspot is trying to connect to http://localhost:8983/opt/apache-solr-3.3.0/example ;)

The correct version:

```
solr:
   hostname: localhost
   port: 8983
   path: /solr
   log_level: WARNING
   pid_dir: /var/run
```

(Also, don't forget to copy Sunspot's standard schema.xml into your Solr directory somewhere under /opt/apache-solr-3.3.0)